# inline-block not working with grid when used for varying width according to content

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm working with grid and the problem i'm facing is inline block is not working with it. i.e I want my div's height and width to vary with the content inside it. If i'm not using grid then it is working fine but with grid it stretch to the column's width

```css
.BotWrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(20px, auto);
  margin-top: 0.8em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.BotWrapper > div {
  margin-left: 2%;
  background: #BEE9E8;
  padding: 1.7%;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 40px;
  min-width: 6em;
  max-width: 20em;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.BotWrapper > div:nth-child(even) {
  background: transparent;
}

UserWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(30px, auto);
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background: blue;
}

.UserWrapper > div {
  float: right;
  margin-right: -2.2em;
  background-color: #62B6CB;
  padding: 1.7%;
  max-width: 20em;
  min-width: 6em;
  min-height: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.UserWrapper > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: transparent;
}

.speech-bubble {
  padding: 5rem;
  border: 2px solid #376996;
  border-top-right-radius: .6em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: .6em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: .6em;
}

.speech-bubble1 {
  position: relative;
  background: #62B6CB;
  border: 2px solid #376996;
  border-top-left-radius: .6em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: .6em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: .6em
}

.timeRight {
  font-size: 0.52em;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -1em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-family: 'Mina', sans-serif;
}

.timeLeft {
  font-size: 0.52em;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -1em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-family: 'Mina', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="msgContainer" id="chat">
  <div class="BotWrapper">
    <div class="speech-bubble z-depth-5">
      <p>Hi</p>
      <p class="timeLeft">02:12:02</p>
    </div>
    <div class=""></div>
  </div>

  <div class="UserWrapper">
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class="speech-bubble1 z-depth-5">
      <p>Bye</p>
      <p class="timeRight">02:12:03</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The first `div` is when i'm using grid and for the second one i have removed `.` from the `UserWrapper` so it is not being executed as a `grid`.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Children in a CSS-Grid become grid-children - `display:inline-block` will not apply.

Comment: @Paulie_D So how do i vary width of the div according to the content

Comment: @Paulie_D created the demo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `justify-items: start` on the container. This aligns items to be flush with the start edge of their cell whereas the default is `stretch` which forces the children to fill the whole width of the cell

[**CSS-Tricks Complete Guide**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

```css
.BotWrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(20px, auto);
  margin-top: 0.8em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  justify-items: start; /* this */
}

.BotWrapper > div {
  margin-left: 2%;
  background: #BEE9E8;
  padding: 1.7%;
  min-height: 40px;
  min-width: 6em;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.BotWrapper > div:nth-child(even) {
  background: transparent;
}

UserWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(30px, auto);
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background: blue;
}

.UserWrapper > div {
  float: right;
  margin-right: -2.2em;
  background-color: #62B6CB;
  padding: 1.7%;
  max-width: 20em;
  min-width: 6em;
  min-height: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.UserWrapper > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: transparent;
}

.speech-bubble {
  padding: 5rem;
  border: 2px solid #376996;
  border-top-right-radius: .6em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: .6em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: .6em;
}

.speech-bubble1 {
  position: relative;
  background: #62B6CB;
  border: 2px solid #376996;
  border-top-left-radius: .6em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: .6em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: .6em
}

.timeRight {
  font-size: 0.52em;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -1em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-family: 'Mina', sans-serif;
}

.timeLeft {
  font-size: 0.52em;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -1em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-family: 'Mina', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="msgContainer" id="chat">
  <div class="BotWrapper">
    <div class="speech-bubble z-depth-5">
      <p>Hi</p>
      <p class="timeLeft">02:12:02</p>
    </div>
    <div class=""></div>
  </div>

  <div class="UserWrapper">
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class="speech-bubble1 z-depth-5">
      <p>Bye</p>
      <p class="timeRight">02:12:03</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```